# Ruby: Class methods and initialization

Tags: ruby, rspec

Currently struggling through an rspec tutorial and would really appreciate some clarification.

Code is:

```
class Book

    attr_reader :title

    def initialize(title=nil)
        @title = title = title && title.capitalize!
    end

    def title=(new_title = nil)
        @title = new_title && new_title.each do |word|
        word.capitalize!
    end
end
```

Two questions:

1. Why are there two sets of `@title` (that is: why is it defined in both `initialize` and `title` as being set = to different things)?
2. Why does the `title` method have an `=` after it? The code breaks if I do not use the `=`.

edit: for the purposes of my rspec tutorial this is the code i finally tried that worked

```
class Book
    attr_accessor :title

    def initialize(title = nil)
        @title = title
    end

    def title=(book_title = nil)
        @title = book_title.capitalize 
    end
end
```

My initial problem was with the title= method. Finally I came upon a thread that explain what method= function was. It is necessary if you want to assign a value to something within a class method (at least that is my understanding at this point. Feel free to correct me).

I would appreciate any tips in this new code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analize that:

```
attr_reader :title
```

Here we are basically defining the method:

```
def title; @title; end
```

which returns the instance variable `@title`.

```
def initialize(title=nil)
    @title = title = title && title.capitalize!
end
```

Here we are defining a 0-1 arguments constructor which can be reduced to:

```
def initialize(title=nil)
    title && @title = title.capitalize
end
```

The fact is that `title` within the constructor is the argument variable and not the `title` or `title=` method, therefore the `title=` method defined later is never called here. Notice that `&&` is used for [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) here.

```
def title=(new_title = nil)
    @title = new_title && new_title.each do |word|
    word.capitalize!
end
```

Here we actually have two syntax errors: the first one is that for `String`s (which I assume is the type of a *title* as it appears to call `String#capitalize!` later) does not have the `each` method. Whoever wrote this probably meant [`String#each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) or to `String#split` it first instead.

The second error is that the block after the `each` is not closed with an `end`.

Now assuming this version instead:

```
def title=(new_title = nil)
    @title = new_title && new_title.split(' ').each { |word| word.capitalize! }.join(' ')
end
```

the `title=` would just assign `title` to the `@title` variable for the same reason (short-circuit evaluation) as before and could be reduced to:

```
def title=(new_title = nil)
    new_title && @title = new_title
end
```

Comment: Very helpful (I'm going to have to read it multiple times, but it is already starting to help me understand). Clarification:  both of the errors you pointed out were me writing the next part of the code. I forgot to change it to its original format before I posted (Sorry! and thanks for correcting those :D).

Comment: My code is not working anymore. When i removed the short-circuit evaluations, as in your examples, it completely broke. my code is 

`class Book`

  `attr_reader :title`

    `def initialize(title = nil)`
      `@title = title.capitalize`
    `end`

    `def title=(new_title = nil)`
       `@title = new_title`
    `end`
`end`

I also tried it with `new_title.split(' ').each do |word|
word.capitalize
end'

as well as `new_title.each_char do |word|
word.capitalize
end'

Comment: I do not think you can shorten the code the way you have. Going from `@title = title = title && title.capitalize!` to `@title = title.capitalize` will now throw an exception if `title` is nil. For the `title=` method, removing the capitalization part would mean that the `new_title` does not get capitalized. Also, you need to `join` the split string (otherwise @title will become an array instead of a string).

Comment: @JustinKo, you are right for most of the things: fixed both the shorten code and added the `join`. But as for the `title=` method, in the original code it capitalizes a local variable that will then get deleted at the end of the block (notice that it is not passed as a reference). Therefore it is an operation that does not affect neither the object nor the external variable passed to `title=`.

Comment: `title=` is using `capitalize!`, which does change the object (ie is different than just `capitalize`). For example, `p ['a', 'b'].each{ |word| word.capitalize! }` will return `["A", "B"]`.

Comment: @JustinKo, yes, but it will only affect the `new_title` local object and not the `Book` object.

Comment: @Jefffrey, I thought the `title=` method is basically doing `@title = 'capital phrase' && 'Capital Phrase'`, which will set @title to 'Capital Phrase'. At least that is what I see when I run the script.

Comment: Can someone explain what exactly `title=` is? I am unsure why I can't just put `def title (argument)` and then define the method as I would regularly do. Why is there an `=` ?

Comment: @SaiDandamudi, the `=` is part of the function name. Ruby allows `?`, `!`, `=` and many other characters to be part of the function name. In that case you can do `obj.title=(other_title)` or `obj.title = other_title` and they will both call the `title=` method. You can also define a `setTitle(other_title)` kind of function, but that's just not the Ruby way. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `initialize` method is called when an instance of the class is constructed.  The `@title = ...` there sets the initial value of `@title`.

The `title=` method is called when someone subsequently sets the value of title on an instance of the class.  It then adjusts the value of `@title` accordingly.  See [Ruby Accessors](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html) for a detailed explanation.

As an example:

```
book = Book.new       # calls initialize
book.title = 'foo'    # calls title=
```

Comment: so `title=` is just a method that calls a different version of @title (which can then be manipulated to do whatever you want it to do)

Comment: It's not a different version of the method, it's a different thing entirely.  title= is a method, @title is an instance variable.

Comment: Ahhh ok. That makes a lot more sense. One more thing: @Jefffrey was saying that I can shorten my code. But it is now breaking when I don't use the `&&` sections. Is there a way to shorten it or should I keep the `&&`s in